# How do I execute a txt file in SAS without read permissions?

Tags: sas

I have a txt file with my personal credentials and some macros underneath that requires these credentials.  I want to be logged in as some other group userid in SAS and run this txt file without revealing my credentials... how do I do this?

I tried to set only execute permissions on the txt file.  And, I used an `%include` statement in SAS but it says there's 'Insufficient authorization' because there's no read permissions.  I don't want to set read permissions because I don't want somebody logged in the group userID to be able to read the file and get my personal credentials.  I do, however, want them to be able to run this file.

```
%include "/home/personalID/LoginPass.txt";
```

> ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access
>   /home/personalID/LoginPass.txt. ERROR: Cannot open %INCLUDE file
>   /home/personalID/LoginPass.txt.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem.  What is it that you are trying to access that needs your credentials?  For example if you are using it to query some external database perhaps you could define a SAS view and give the users access to the view.  Or give the users access to the database have the program read their credentials from a file they create.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute a file without READ permission, because you need to read it in order to execute it.

If you wish to share credentials, the recommended way is to use an authentication domain in SAS Metadata (speak to your admin to set this up).

If your SAS program is executed as a stored process, you could allow only the `sassrv` (or equivalent) system account READ access to your `secret.txt` file (along with the `nosource2` option) to securely share credentials that way also.

The following articles will be helpful:

https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2010/11/23/five-strategies-to-eliminate-passwords-from-your-sas-programs/

https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2018/01/16/hide-rest-api-tokens/

If you decide to use `proc pwencode` to obscure your passwords, be sure to use `sas003` or above.  `sas002` and below are very easy to reverse engineer, and should never be used.

Comment: Thanks.  I already got the credentials to not appear in the logs.  But, if a user logs onto the server and tries to access my file from the terminal, they are able to get my password.  Anyway around this?

Comment: If you have any files with your passwords, they should be readonly to everyone except you.  You cannot let other users read (or execute) that file without exposing your password.  As @Tom mentions, it would help to know more about what you are trying to achieve (maybe create a new question for that)